# Mysql to return several rows

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Good morning,

I am trying to run a stored procedure which would return several rows :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_tbl_openweathermap_cities_get_city_ids`(OUT `p_ID` INT)
NO SQL
SELECT id_city FROM tbl_openweathermap_cities
ORDER BY id_city
```

When I run the stored procedure, it says :

```
id_city
-------
1234 
6987 
10000


p_ID
----
NULL
```

I understand the first part (aka the rows mentioned under 'id_city' but I don't understand why it returns null. What did I miss?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Best wishes,
Laurent

Comment: You have an OUT parameter, since you dont do anything with it it returns NULL

Comment: Does anyone know how I can ensure that the out parameter will return a value which is not null ? Many thanks for your help. Best wishes, Laurent